# How can I identify only base tables when iterating through all tables in SQL smo?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-smo

This is my code:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(con));
server.ConnectionContext.Connect();

foreach (Table table in server.Databases[sqlDatabase].Tables)
{
    if (table <is a base table>)
```

Basically this pulls back views as well I think. The SQL I use to identify the wanted tables is:

`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'`

However there doesn't seem to be a `TABLE_TYPE` property on the results which are `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TableCollection`. According to SQL, the TABLE_TYPE is either `BASE TABLE` or `VIEW` so only two possibilities.

How can I identify only tables (and not views)?

Comment: Looping over the TablesCollection will not enumerate the Views. Indeed you have a Views collection as  _server.Databases[sqlDatabase].Views_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looping over the TablesCollection will not enumerate the Views, so your code should works as it is without worrying about Views.

Indeed you have a Views collection as `server.Databases[sqlDatabase].Views`

And, in this collection as well as in the Tables collection, you could differentiate your own views/tables from the system views/tables using the property `IsSystemObject`

```
var myTables = server.Databases[sqlDatabase].Views
                    .Cast<Table> => !v.IsSystemObject));

var myViews = server.Databases[sqlDatabase].Views
                    .Cast<View>().Where(v => !v.IsSystemObject));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's okay what you did. You can find views this way -> `WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'`, so your select do what you want. I recommend you to open management studio or any other program that allows you to query data and run this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'
```